# UIImageView Fade In/Out with NSArray

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, nsarray

I have an NSArray of images that I want to fade in/out between each other (much like how Flickr handles their home screen).

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to utilize the `[UIView beginAnimations];` with the NSArray... any idea?

My code is below.

Thanks in advance!

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"show_robmachado.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"show_losness.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"show_blanchard.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"show_tonino.jpg"],
                         nil];

    homeAnimation.animationImages = myImages;
    homeAnimation.animationRepeatCount = 0; // 0 = loops forever
    homeAnimation.animationDuration = 7.0;
    [homeAnimation startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array method is really for simple frame-based animations, not for transitions.

Instead I would have two UIImageViews at the same position, and set up a timer that would work through the array, using UIView animations to animate one image view fading to an alpha of 0 and the other to an alpha of 1.  Then you'd get a kind of fading switch you are going for.

The .image property on a UIImageView might also be animatable, try in a timed loop changing .image on an image view in a UIView based animation block and see if you get a cross-fade.